# Moq: How to use a mock object as an interface of another mock object

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, moq

**Context**

I am currently implementing some unit tests for my ASP.NET WebApi application and for that I decided to use Moq as my mocking framework. A tool I already know quite well, but I am not yet an expert with it.

For some of my tests I want to mock the behavior of a DbContext. This works well for all normal cases but then I want to add an interface to it and use another mock object to setup the behaviors that my DbContext should have when it has been casted to this interface (the code below might be more explanatory).

**Implementation**

```
// Create the mocked objects with the MockBehavior.Strict option
IPermissionContainer permissionContainer = MockedPermissionContainer().Object;
Mock<DbContext> dbContext = MockedAccountContext(expectedAccount);

// This is how I try to set my permissionContainer as the returned object when casting the DbContext to an IPermissionContainer
dbContext.As<IPermissionContainer>().SetReturnsDefault(permissionContainer);

// Both of these tests are working fine
Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IPermissionContainer>(dbContext.Object);
Assert.NotNull((IPermissionContainer)dbContext.Object);

// This first test accesses the permissionContainer directly and executes normally
var test1 = permissionContainer.GetUserPermissions(_cancellationTokenSource.Token, "Account", requestContext.Object);

// This second test try to access the permissionContainer that was setup earlier but it throws a Moq.MockException (see below)
var test2 = ((IPermissionContainer)dbContext.Object).GetUserPermissions(_cancellationTokenSource.Token, "Account", requestContext.Object);
```

> Moq.MockException : IPermissionContaine.GetUserPermissions(System.Threading.CancellationToken, "Account", Mock.Object) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict.
>
> All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.

**Problem**

The exception says that the GetUserPermissions method was not setup correctly, even though the first test success indicates the contrary. So this probably means that the object returned by the cast does not implement the behavior of the permissionContainer object and the SetReturnsDefault() method probably doesn't return the object that was passed in.

My problem is that I don't know if the SetReturnsDefault() is used correctly in this case (I tried to look at the [Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and the [API](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/Moq/Moq/Mock/M/SetReturnsDefault(TReturn)) documentations but there is nothing for this method there).

If it is used correctly, then it might be a bug so I could open an issue on GitHub and mock my objects differently.
If not, then do you know if there is a way to use my permissionContainer as the implementation of the IPermissionContainer on the DbContext? Or maybe if it is an implementation that is not recommended?

**Finally** I know that it might sound strange to mock my two objects separately but in my case I think it might ease my development and save me a lot of time. Besides, I'm interested to know if it's me or Moq who is acting badly in this case.

Comment: Do you setup GetUserPermissions somewhere?

Comment: Yes, it is set on the MockedPermissionContainer function. Otherwise the line with "test1" would fail.